# postgresql syntax error?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't identify the syntax mistake on this query, where´s the syntax mistake?

```
select c_name, c_address, c_mktsegment , count(*) as cnt customer join orders on c_custkey=o_custkey 
where
(c_name like %r% AND c_address like %a%) OR c_mktsegment like ='%t%'   
group by c_name, c_address, c_mktsegment having count(*)>2;
```

Comment: No `FROM` clause ? With a join ?

Answer (score 4):

One error is you have missing quotes here:

```
(c_name like %r% AND c_address like %a%)
```

Should be:

```
(c_name like '%r%' AND c_address like '%a%')
```

---

Another problem mentioned in the comments is you missed the FROM keyword:

```
select c_name, c_address, c_mktsegment , count(*) as cnt customer
```

Should be:

```
SELECT c_name, c_address, c_mktsegment , count(*) as cnt
FROM customer
```

---

There may also be other errors. But you can be sure that both these problems *are* actually problems and they *do* need to be fixed. I'd strongly recommend that you fix them before further investigating any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding one more thing in the answer given by Mark Byers is that

**you cannot use = with like operator**

so you have to replace `OR c_mktsegment like ='%t%`' **with** `OR c_mktsegment like '%t%'`